# Adding OSGi manifest metadata to LPGL Library

Tags: hibernate, licensing, osgi, lgpl

I am wondering what the implications are for adding OSGi manifest headers to the `META-INF/manifest.MF` file to a LGPL library.

Its not changing the source, but the binary JAR is modified. The changes are clearly visible and plain text in the JAR file.

I understand the LPGL would require me to release the *source changes* only. What exactly would that mean?

The specific example I have in mind is Hibernate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LGPL does not require you to release the source upfront. You only have to provide it if someone asks for it.

In you case you would then have to release (with LGPL license) the source for the build that adds the manifest. Or if you do it by hand the new manifest file and instructions how to apply it.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks, just wasn't sure of the specifics.